# Gizmo doesn't align with object local axis

Tags: modeling, axis

I can't seem to utilize the local axis after rotating an object.
I've tried applying the rotation and position but that doesn't help.

[image]

I've linked the file for you to look at, feel free to reward yourself with this 3d file of an arm, with textures included, as a token of appreciation for taking the time to help me with this issue.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19hTyS8-mBbIGIO6iXk5Mf0HXFSw3lUsT/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the *Move* tool activated, you have a second dropdown menu for the *Transform Orientation* which determines how the gizmo is shown. In your case it is set to *Gimbal*.

The same would happen if you enabled the *Move* gizmo in the *Overlays* without activating the *Move* tool. In the *Overlays* you can choose an orientation for the gizmo as well, but other than the tool gizmo there will not be a second orientation shown in the menu bar which makes it even more confusing.

[image: tool gizmo orientation]

The default orientation which is always shown is the one that will be used whenever you hit <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> in combination with an axis letter to move, rotate or scale something along this axis. The second orientation which the gizmo uses is the one where you can move (or rotate or scale depending on which gizmo or tool is enabled) along a gizmo axis by dragging on it.

Now I'm not gonna pretend to understand what exactly *Gimbal* orientation is, I'd rather quote the *Blender Reference Manual* on this. But it doesn't really matter, even with other gizmo orientations you can experience this apparent discrepancy between chosen orientation and shown orientation of the gizmo.

From the manual:

- **Gimbal**

  Orient the transformation axes to visualize the workings of the object’s Rotation Mode. This is specifically useful for the Euler modes, where the object is rotated one axis at a time: the rotation axes don’t stay perpendicular to each other and might even overlap, a phenomenon known as gimbal lock that complicates animation.